# Shuffle emissions of a Flux in Reactor?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a `Flux` and I would like to shuffle its emissions.

So for emissions:

```
1, 2, 3, ...
```

I would like to have:

```
32, 5, 9, ...
```

Is it possible in Reactor?

Comment: I think that you might add more details in  your question, to allow answers that better fit your need, or at least that can provide you with good insight of what is or is not possible for your case. The answer from @ricard-kollcaku is good in the specific cases of a random generator source, but to shuffle an existing data source, you'll need buffering in some way, and also be cautious about the consequences on the thoughput (for example: the first snippet from ricard answer might behave very differently depending on subscription demand, flatMap concurrency, other intermediate operators, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Reactor has a function that shuffles for you but there is one workaround you can do.
If you want to keep the upper stream as it is,

```
Random random = new Random();
Flux.range(1,256)
    .flatMap(integer -> Flux.just(integer).delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(random.nextInt(256))))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

}

If you need random elements:

```
Flux.range(1,256)
        .map(integer -> random.nextInt(256))
        .subscribe(System.out::println)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another more elegant way is to use `Flux.generate()` to emit a random value:

```
Random random = new Random();

Flux.generate(sink -> sink.next(random.nextInt(256)))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```